# How to run single selenium test case in two different nodes?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc, selenium-grid

I am new to selenium,I need to run my single selenium test case in two different nodes using FIREFOX browser (selenium grid),I have started my hub using below command

java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar -role hub

Node 1:
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar -role webdriver -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -port 9595

Node 2: 
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar -role webdriver -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -port 8585

two  nodes has been created to hub .But when i run a testcase in hub,only one node is executing the test case and the other node remain available but not executing the testcase .

2) The node is selected randomly by hub while executing the testcase.

**My question:
Run testcase in both the nodes simultaneously**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nodes can be declared as follow:-

**Node 1 for chrome** java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\drivers\chromedriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -port 8585 -browserName=chrome

**Node 2 for firefox:** java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -port 9595 -browserName=firefox

You need to have following testng.xml to run same test case on different browsers:-

```
<suite name="Selenium TestNG Suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="5">

    <test name="Selenium TestNG - 1">
        <parameter name="browser" value="firefox" />
        <parameter name="port" value="9595" />
        <classes>
            <class name="grid.testcase" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Selenium TestNG - 2">
        <parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
        <parameter name="port" value="8585" />
        <classes>
            <class name="grid.testcase" />
        </classes>
    </test>

</suite>
```

In your test case, write code something like this:-

```
package grid;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class testcase {
    public WebDriver driver=null;
    @Parameters({"browser","port"})
    @BeforeClass
    public void initialize(String browser, String port) throws MalformedURLException{
        DesiredCapabilities capability= new DesiredCapabilities();
        capability.setBrowserName(browser);
        driver= new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:".concat(port).concat("/wd/hub")), capability);

    }
    @Test
    public void testThis() throws InterruptedException {
        String url="https://www.google.com";
        driver.get(url);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        //do something
        driver.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Vishal Jagtap,U have created node chrome and node firefox in same machine or two different machines? and I followed your code,but I am getting the following error  "Parameter 'browser' is required by @Configuration on method initialize but has not been marked  or defined"

Comment: I have created both nodes on local machine. If you want to create a node on remote machine which connects to hub on your local machine, then use following command line on your remote machine -                java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar -role webdriver -hub http://192.12.13.1:4444/grid/register -port 8585   here 192.12.13.1 is IP address of machine where hub is running. Make sure Your remote machine can communicate/access your local machine

Comment: Also, about error "Parameter 'browser' is required by @Configuration on method initialize but has not been marked or defined" - Make sure you have name 'browser' is correctly spelled and mentioned both in xml file and in your test case.

Comment: Thanks Vishal,'browser; is correctly spelled in both in xml file and in your test case. but even then I am getting the same error as aboved mentioned.

Comment: Hi, actually chrome should be on 8585 and firefox on 9595, it got interchanged in xml and node statement. I have edited and corrected it. So, again just be sure that chrome node port number and that mentioned in xml matches, same for firefox. Try this time.

Comment: I Changed the port number as you mentioned even then I am getting the same error

Comment: Ok, is it possible for you to post xml, testcase, node commands here. I could probably take a look at it; as for me its working fine for above files I have posted.

Comment: or you can email me on vishal6126@gmail.com

Comment: I think, your are directly running testcase.java file as 'TestNg Test', In this case it will throw error that you have mentioned. Because it does not get first paramenter 'browser' itself which is mentioned in testng.xml.                    You should run testng.xml as 'TestNg Test' and not .java file.

Answer (score 0):

1. I am not sure what framework you are using. I did parallel execution using "testng" framework.
2. For using testng you have to add testng jar file in your project build path or if you used IDE like eclipse add testng plugin.
3. Then create your class with proper annotation(ie. @test).
4. Create testNG.xml file and configure the things.(make sure You mentioned parallel=2. the count 2 is only how many test you want to execute in parallel)
5. Then right click the xml file and click runas testNG..

---

Refer :

1. [testng-executing-parallel-tests](http://howtodoinjava.com/2014/12/02/testng-executing-parallel-tests/)
2. [parallel-execution-of-test-methods-in-testng](http://seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/parallel-execution-of-test-methods-in-testng)

Comment: dinesh,Thanks for your reply.I want to run test on two different machines.What u meant parallel is, running various testcase on same machine.But i want to run my testcase in firefox in node1,run my testcase in chrome in node2,run my testcase in IE in node3..

Comment: Here Node means different machine